# SharePoint 2013 - Server is not responding/no connectivity to server issue when opening Excel files after removing support for TLS1.0/TLS1.1

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, excel, windows-7, tls

We're having an issue that seems to be affecting Windows 7 users whereby **they cannot click to open Excel files** stored in a SharePoint 2013 Foundation document library. They get an error that either says the server isn't responding, or there is no connectivity to the server.

The same users also seem to be unable to export a list to Excel getting the message:

> "cannot connect to the server at this time. Your changes cannot be
>   saved."

I've added the domain of our SP farm to Trusted locations in Excel. I've added to compatibility view and Trusted Sites in IE.
I've removed "**Check for server certificate revocation**" in *IE>Internet Options>Advance Settings>Security* - this was a recommendation somewhere else.

I've worked through this [article on the server and user machine as directed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-and-ssl-support-in-sharepoint-2013)

[I've also looked at this solution for SP 2016 which is taken from the article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249784/sharepoint-project-server-2016-no-connectivity-with-the-server)

Needless to say, none of the above have worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is [Microsoft Documentation for enabling TSL1.2 on SharePoint 2016.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-support-in-sharepoint-server-2016)

Verify you have done everything and read Step 3 where are information about Client Computers.

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: That's sorted it, thanks Zdenēk. I'd tried everything for SP2013, but not 2016.

Comment: A word of warning though. This could break other systems. We had an ACT crm database and doing this broke the connection for this particular user.